# How to restrict call multiple api call in useEffect in react-native?

Tags: react-native, performance-testing

I am new in `React-Native`, I am facing one issue in my app and not able to resolved that yet. All thing is working but first time API being calling two time unnecessary.

Here is my useEffect method :-

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (transactions.length === 0) {
      setIsAPICall(true);
    }
    getTransactions().then((response: any) => {
      dispatch(actionTransitionsBadge(0));
      setTransactions(response);
      setIsAPICall(false);
    });
  }, [user, onChainBalance]);
```

In this method I have to get transaction list when component first time open. After that I have to refresh this list when `user` and `onChainBalance` get updated. The thing is working but when I am loading this component first time then the api is calling multiple time.

What I can do to manage this flow that once component load then api call once after then when my two `state` changed the api call again.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use [user] or [onChainBalance] for useEffect second parameter.
The api is called multiple times because it is called when the user and onChainBalance update each other.

Answer (score 0):

Put your getTransactions in the useCallback, like this:

```
  const fetchData=useCallback(
     () => {
     getTransactions().then((response: any) => {
      dispatch(actionTransitionsBadge(0));
      setTransactions(response);
      setIsAPICall(false);
    });
     },
     [],
    )
```

Then call fetchData in the useEffect

Comment: Still calling multiple time

Comment: Check in your package.json which react version you are using, if it is 18 check this https://upmostly.com/tutorials/why-is-my-useeffect-hook-running-twice-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Details where you can useEffect .

1. useEffect(() => {},)
2. useEffect(() => {},[])
3. useEffect(() => {},[dependency_array])

Here I am explaining them one by one

```
The first would call on every render 

The Second would call two time 

the third would call two times and when the dependency array changes
```

Here is your use Case

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(user !== null &&  user !== undefined && transactions.length === 0){
        getTransactions().then((response: any) => {
         dispatch(actionTransitionsBadge(0));
         setTransactions(response);
         setIsAPICall(false);
       });
    }
  }, [user, onChainBalance]);
```

but Still this is not a good method. you should use [react-query](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/) or [redux-toolkit-query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)